# Set parent class attribute in child class constructor

Tags: python

This question is posed as a general Python question, but will be exemplified using Kubeflow Pipelines SDK, `kfp==1.8.12`. In this module, I want to create a helper class around the class `dsl.ContainerOp` to simplify a lot of my work. As a minimal example, below I use this class to create a component as such:

```py
from kfp import dsl

name = 'My name'
image = 'My image'
docker_entrypoint = "/main.py"
docker_args = [
        '--arg1', 'some arg',
        '--arg2', 'some other arg'
    ]

component = dsl.ContainerOp(
    name=name,
    image=image,
    arguments=[docker_entrypoint] + docker_args
)
```

Then, I would like to set one of its attributes that relates to caching as such;

```py
use_caching = False
if use_caching:
    staleness = "P30D"
else:
    staleness = "P0D"

component.execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness = staleness
```

which works fine, as expected. Now, I would like to create a `ContainerOpHelper` class, to simplify a lot of my argument passing (the "real" code has a lot of parameters). **Problem: I need to access the attribute `execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness` from the class, but I can't figure out how!** Here is the helper class, and my attempt to access the attribute;

```py
class ContainerOpHelper(dsl.ContainerOp):
    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        image: str,
        docker_entrypoint: str = None,
        docker_args: list = None,
        use_caching: bool = None
    ):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            image=image,
            arguments=([docker_entrypoint] if docker_entrypoint else []) + (docker_args if docker_args else [])
        )
        if use_caching:
            staleness = "P30D"
        else:
            staleness = "P0D"
        # Tried to be creative; but doesnt work
        super.__setattr__("execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness", staleness)
```

This helper class can then be used as such;

```py
component = ContainerOpHelper(
    name='My name',
    image='My image',
    docker_entrypoint="/main.py",
    docker_args=[
        '--arg1', 'some arg',
        '--arg2', 'some other arg'
    ],
    use_caching=False
)
```

Since the attribute `execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness` is "many levels deep", I'm not sure how I can set it in my helper class. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean: self.execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness = staleness ?

Comment: Well, that was easy. I really overthought that! Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is only available because you had already called `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple, as provided by the comment of @quamrana.

Simply set it straight in the child class constructor as such;

```py
self.execution_options.caching_strategy.max_cache_staleness = staleness
```